# How to minimize an Android app on Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I tried:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
if Key = vkHardwareBack then begin
Key := 0;
Form1.WindowState := TWindowState.wsMinimized; // Also tried Application.MainForm
end;
end;
```

But when you hit the first time the screen gets black, when you hit the second time the app closes. How to avoid this?

Comment: Well asked question! You just missed one extra condition in your trial code, when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: @Victoria I used this code as an example, the actual code has several conditions when vkHardwareBack is pressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The android way would be to switch to the desktop instead of trying to minimize your app. There are at least two ways to achieve this:

First possibility is to call:

```
MainActivity.movetasktoback(true);
```

Second possibility is:

```
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
  Intent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_HOME);
  tandroidhelper.activity.startActivity(Intent);
```

However I noticed that under Delphi both ways do seem to lead to a black screen app when reactivated.

Comment: I tested the second method on Android 5 Lollipop, no black screen was shown in or out!